# Ampersand Model Validations Mixin not waiting for mysql query result

Tags: node.js, ampersand, ampersand.js

I am using ampersand-model-validations-mixin in my nodejs project.
The validation syntax is

```
validations: { 'type': { type: function(){ return validateType(this._values.type); }, msg: 'type cannot be blank and it should be unique' },
```

validateType is a function which checks from database whether it is unique or not.

```
function validateType(type) {if (_.isEmpty(type)) {return false;  } else {var searchData = '{"type" : "' + type + '"}';dao.searchDocument(process.env.DEVICE_CONNECTOR_TYPE_MODEL, searchData)   .then(function(resp) {if (!_.isEmpty(resp)) {return false;}else{return true;}});}}
```

But it is not waiting for the result and directly saving it .

Any idea on how to do this ??

Answer (score 0):

For "future generations": currently async tests are not supported, as mentioned here: https://github.com/jarredwitt/ampersand-model-validations-mixin/issues/1

So you would need to extend the mixin's functionality if you want this kind of thing.